# Can I create a hybrid Content / TaskPane addin in Excel?

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins

We can create TaskPane or Content Addins in Excel.

I'd like to create a hybrid App that does the following (a single manifest):

- Open a Taskpane with 3 buttons.
- Each button opens a different Content addin in the worksheet.
- The final scenario: I'd have 3 different content (visualizations) embeded in the worksheet, and I can close them any time I want.

Is this possible? I think it is not by reading [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/overview/add-in-manifests.md) document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Even if that was possible, with the current set of APIs you won't be able to open the content add-in from a regular button, you need to define that button in the manifest.